# How can I make a custom digit/time input for AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, numbers

I want to make an input box that prevents the user from entering bad data and formats the user's input on blur.

I want to use a custom directive because the input type=number has some features that I do not want.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="time" />
```

When the user types in a bad entry, I want to prevent them from seeing that and going into the model. e.g 1a the 'a' will not be shown.
If they type 99:c they will not see the 'c'
or 55:10: they will not see the second ':'

I want these to be valid entries:

x number of hours : y number of minutes

e.g.

- 99:32 - 99 hours and 32 minutes
- 9 - 9 hours
- 0:02 - 2 minutes

Here is what I have so far:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Nkjr5ahjBj4OQ3q2fMhL?p=preview

Comment: use `ng-pattern`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Element Directive input[time] is used to create HTML time input with time validation and transformation.

The input must be provided in the format ISO-8601, i.e local time format HH: mm: ss, for example, 15:35:10

The data model must be a Date Object, time zones used to read/write Date instance is defined using ngModel.

**Syntax:**

```
<input type="time"
       ng-model="string"
       [name="string"]
       [min="string"]
       [max="string"]
       [required="string"]
       [ng-required="string"]
       [ng-change="string"]>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>AngularJS Directives : input[time]</title>
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <style>
      b{font-family:Papyrus; color:#fa4b2a; font-size: 20px;} 
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="timeDemo">
  <script>
 angular.module('timeDemo', [])
   .controller('timeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.sample = {
       value: new Date(1999, 0, 1, 15, 30, 0)
     };
   }]);
</script>
<form name="demoForm" ng-controller="timeController as timeCtrl">
   <label for="sampleInput">Select a time from 6 am to 6 pm</label>
   <input type="time" id="sampleInput" name="input" ng-model="sample.value"
       placeholder="HH:mm:ss" min="06:00:00" max="18:00:00" required />
  <!-- min 6 am and max 6 pm i.e 18:00 -->
   <div role="alert">
     <span class="error" ng-show="demoForm.input.$error.required">
        Input is Required!</span>
     <!-- Required Error  -->
     <span class="error" ng-show="demoForm.input.$error.time">
       Input Date is  not Valid!</span>
    <!-- Validation Error -->
     
   </div>
  <i>value = <b>{{sample.value | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.input.$valid = <b>{{demoForm.input.$valid}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.input.$error = <b>{{demoForm.input.$error}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.$valid = <b>{{demoForm.$valid}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.$error.required = <b>{{!!demoForm.$error.required}}</b></i><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```